# Google Apps Engine PHP Mail API - $image_data

Tags: php, api, google-app-engine

in the official GAE PHP Mail Api doc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/ they show this example:

```
use \google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

// Notice that $image_data is the raw file data of the attachment.
try
{
  $message = new Message();
  $message->setSender("from@google.com");
  $message->addTo("to@google.com");
  $message->setSubject("Example email");
  $message->setTextBody("Hello, world!");
  $message->addAttachment('image.jpg', $image_data, $image_content_id);
  $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
  // ...
}
```

but they dont explain how to fill $image_data with an uploaded static file.
any help ? if it can be explicit it will be great

thanks
diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use file_get_contents() to retrieve the data you want to send as part of the email.

```
$image_data = file_get_contents('path/to/static/file.jpg');
```

Or you can send an image stored in Cloud Storage

```
$image_data = file_get_contents('gs://my_bucket/path/to/file.jpg');
```