# GAE PHP - mail api - HTML content

Tags: php, google-app-engine, html-email

This question is related to

[Google Apps Engine PHP Mail API - $image_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020871/google-apps-engine-php-mail-api-image-data/29020989#29020989)

I couldnt find any documentation or example on how to send HTML content from a php script hosted on GAE using mail-api.

My challenge is to send a very basic email with a background color or image, a table to tab data, and a header image (all embeded)

Could anybody reply with this issue please ? If changes must be done on `yaml` don't forget to mention it please ?

Comment: removed thanks + unwanted words

Answer (score 0):

While not (yet) documented, you can use the standard mail() function to send emails on App Engine. See https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ for an example on how to send HTML emails.